# OpenRTB Ad Request / Sell Request API

Tags: real-time

I was wondering if Ad Request/Sell Request is supported on OpenRTB. Has anyone tried this?

Here's the link to their API documentation: http://www.iab.net/media/file/OpenRTB_API_Specification_Version2.0_FINAL.PDF

As you can see, it is mostly focused on Bid Requests (Buyers' side). I was wondering if anyone tried coding up API requests on the Seller Side (Post Ads, etc) or if it is even supported at all?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOSd.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!